# Unexpected behaviour when using inheritance

Tags: c++

I have a `Base` class, which is then inherited by `Foo`, and `Foo` is in turn inehrited by `Bar`.

Here is the header file `base.h` for my `Base` class:

```
#pragma once

class Base {
    public:
        void runExample();

    private:
        virtual void print();
};
```

And the implementation `base.cpp`:

```
#include "base.h"

void Base::runExample() {
    print();
}

void Base::print() {};
```

Here is the header file `foo.h` for my `Foo` class:

```
#pragma once
#include "../base/base.h"

class Foo : public Base {
    public:
        Foo();

    private:
        void print();

        const char* toPrint;
};
```

And the implementation `foo.cpp`:

```
#include "foo.h"

Foo::Foo() {
    toPrint = "Hello Foo";
}

void Foo::print() {
    std::cout << toPrint << std::endl;
}
```

Here is the header file `bar.h` for my `Bar` class:

```
#pragma once
#include "../foo/foo.h"

class Bar : public Foo {
    public:
        Bar();

    private:
        const char* toPrint; // "overrides" toPrint from parent class Foo?
};
```

And the implementation `bar.cpp`:

```
#include "bar.h"

Bar::Bar() {
    toPrint = "Hello Bar";
}
```

And finally, my main function:

```
#include "../bar/bar.h"
int main() {
    Bar bar = Bar();
    bar.runExample();
}
```

So, I have this kind of relationship between the classes:

`Bar` *is a* `Foo` which *is a* `Base`.

What I was expecting to see in the output was "Hello Bar", but what I actually see is "Hello Foo".

If I "override" the `print` method declared in `Foo` in `Bar` to print `toPrint` then I get the expected result, however this seems to break the point of inheritance; i.e. why would I need to re-define the functionality when it's already defined.

What I am expecting is that when `Bar.print()` is invoked, it uses `Foos` implementation, but the actual field `toPrint` has been "replaced" with the value inside the `Bar` implementation.

I am very new to C++, and I'm coming from a Kotlin background. Forgive me if this is like C++ 101 basics, but I'm pretty confused as to why this is happening. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You can't "override" member variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, data members cannot be "overridden" as you expect, and a reference to `toPrint` will not be dynamically bound to equally named data members in subclasses.

With

```
class Bar : public Foo {
        ...
        const char* toPrint; // "overrides" toPrint from parent class Foo?
};
```

you introduce a member variable `Bar::toPrint` next to `Foo::toPrint`, which is inherited. The code

```
void Foo::print() {
    std::cout << toPrint << std::endl;
}
```

will always stick to the `toPrint`-member in his scope, i.e. to `Foo::toPrint`.

The following code illustrates this behaviour:

```
struct Base {
    const char* toPrint = "Base";
    virtual void print() const { cout << toPrint << std::endl; }
};

struct Derived: public Base {
    const char* toPrint = "Derived";
    
    void printBoth() const { cout << "own:" << toPrint << "; inherited: " << Base::toPrint << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
    
    Derived d;
    
    cout << "call inherited method print:" << std::endl;
    d.print();
    
    cout << "call method printBoth, showing both data members:" << std::endl;
    d.printBoth();
}
```

Output:

```
call inherited method print:
Base
call method printBoth, showing both data members:
own:Derived; inherited: Base
```

Comment: Aye makes sense, but, if I make `toPrint` in `Foo` a protected member variable, and remove the re-definition of `toPrint` from `Bar` then it does appear to be "overridden" by `Bar`s constructor

Comment: If you remove `Bar::toPrint`, then you inherit data member `Foo::toPrint` and can access it through `toPrint`; you don't override it, you just assign a different value to `Foo::toPrint` in the constructor of `Bar`.

Comment: Aha I see, makes perfect sense. I think I was brain farting quite hard because I've got info overload from learning the new syntax + the overhead of it all being quite different/new compared to Java/Kotlin land. Thanks for your help Stephan!

Comment: So, not overriding it, but simply setting it to a different value in Bar's constructor. Cool, makes sense.  And of course, in my question code, I wasn't "overriding" at all, I was simply declaring a private variable in Bar which happened to have the same name as the private member in Foo, and obviously, because Foos member was private, the compiler wans't complaining the names were the same, but I wasn't "overriding" anything. Lol what an idiot xD

Comment: you can even make both `toPrint` public; the compiler will not complain, since `Foo::toPrint` is different from `Bar::toPrint`. No overriding, no name clash on data members. See extended answer.

Comment: Oh god, that sounds like it could get confusing! That would certainly *not* compile in Java land (using same name for variable that is exposed from parent class). Not sure how I feel about that

Comment: That's just the rules :-)